# Laravel lightbox to show view/form

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have fleshed out a Laravel project but wanting to do something a little different, I am using Bootstrap so the standard nav and modal for the popout.

I am wanting to show the modal with the registration or login form inside, but as you can appreciate the way it is currently built, once you hit the login or register link it just renders the page view.

So I have my views/layouts/navigation.blade.php

```
<div class="container navigation">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
            <li class="navbar-right"><a href="{{ URL::route('home') }}">Home</a></li>
      <div class="container">
            @if(Auth::check())
                <li><a href="{{ URL::route('account-sign-out') }}">Sign out</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{ URL::route('account-change-password') }}">Change password</a></li>
            @else
                <li><a href="{{  URL::route('account-sign-in') }}">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{  URL::route('account-create') }}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"">Sign Up</button></a></li>
            @endif
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

And seperate to this I have my views/account/create.blade.php & views/account/signin.php

```
@extends('layout.main')

@section('content')

    <form action="{{ URL::route('account-create-post') }}" method="post">

        <div class="field">
            Email: <input type="text" name="email"{{ (Input::old('email')) ? ' value="' . e(Input::old('email')) . '"' : '' }}>
            @if($errors->has('email'))
                {{ $errors->first('email') }}
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username"{{ (Input::old('email')) ? ' value="' . e(Input::old('username')) . '"' : '' }}>
            @if($errors->has('username'))
                {{ $errors->first('username') }}
            @endif          
        </div>      

        <div class="field">
            Password: <input type="password" name="password">
            @if($errors->has('password'))
                {{ $errors->first('password') }}
            @endif          
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            Password Again: <input type="password" name="password_again">
            @if($errors->has('password_again'))
                {{ $errors->first('password_again') }}
            @endif          
        </div>          

        <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
        {{ Form::token() }}
    </form>

@stop
```

Really I wanting the button in the nav to fire up the modal and show the forms inside? Amy ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll basically be using Javascript on the client to display the form and process the request to the server and the server's response. I would:

1. Pick a CSS/Javascript framework that will display a modal form for you
2. Put your normal form generation inside the dialog it shows
3. Have a Javascript handler on the submit button of the modal dialog that makes an AJAX post to a new RESTful HTTP endpoint in Laravel that calls the same logic your standard signup form uses, but sends back a response your AJAX code will understand (e.g. either successful or failed, with an error message).

Answer (score 0):

I hope i got the question right. The Key to achieve what you want should be a concept called **nested views**, which is very well explained on [this coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/2v7urq/multiple-and-nested-sub-view-in-laravel-4). Also, check out the [laravel docs on views](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views) (passage *Passing A Sub-View To A View*).

You would have to create a view for your login-form an nest it in the login modal as well as in the standard login-view (if you have one). Hope this helps.